# How to push text from app to notification bar?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to push text from app to notification bar offline without any services?

Comment: hey http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , i will suggest a read ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the proper documentation.

[Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here i wrote a function in android  to get text as parameter and generate the notification in android.

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
  mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  notificationIntent.putExtra("NotificationIntent", true);
  notificationIntent.setFlags(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);
  notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
    this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("MDM GCM.")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg.toString());
  mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
  mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```